# Why is my RMarkdown summary table only showing on one PDF page, where is the rest?

Tags: r, r-markdown, vtable

I'm trying to create a summary table with the package vtable. I do get a table but somehow the font size is super large and not the whole table is shown? I'm really at a loss here. I have spent hours on it, but could not find a solution... Can please someone tell me how to get a smaller table (font size and the whole table in a pdf document?

```
---
title: "Example"
date: "22 March 2021"
output: 
  pdf_document
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(vegan)
library(vtable)




{r dune}
data(dune.env)



{r plot1, echo = F,results='asis',out.width='10%',message=F, fig.show='hold'}
st(dune.env,summ=c('mean(x)','median(x)','min(x)','max(x)'),group="Management",group.long = TRUE,out="latex")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `sumtable` with `out = 'latex'` applies a LaTeX `\resizebox{\textwidth}` to the table to make it fit horizontally on the page. When the table is very narrow and tall, though, like this one, the `resizebox` can scale it to be *bigger* (making the text big).

You can control the width of the table with the `fit.page` option, which scales the horizontal width of the table. By default it's `'\\textwidth'`, but you could do, for example, `.6\\textwidth` to only fill 60% of the horizontal space. This is what I get with `fit.page='.5\\textwidth'`:

[image: Table filling 50% of horizontal space]

Now, this makes the text tiny, but it does fit. This is a consequence of LaTeX giving tall tables a hard time, and having no built-in support for multi-page tables. So it just fills up a page and the rest isn't shown. This is a LaTeX thing, not `sumtable`. There isn't currently support for multi-page LaTeX tables in `sumtable`/**vtable**. However, you could add `keep_tex: true` to your YAML, then after the fact go in and edit the TeX file to use the **longtable** LaTeX package, which adds support for multi-page tables, and turn the `\begin{table}` into `\begin{longtable}`, etc..